# Swift 4 NSExpression with Multiple Functions

Tags: swift, nspredicate, nsexpression

So I have a string `formula` that let's say is:

```
let testValue = 10
let formula = "(max(testValue - 20,0) * 14) + testValue - max(testValue - 20,0)"
```

I can do simple arithmetic, multiplication, division, subtracts, ect but how would I combine the Max function into this string?

I was thinking I would have to change `max` to something that I can substring and then do each function individual and loop through the instances, but is there a better way or is that the way to do it? Like `|@Max(x,y)|`.

Also, is there a specific syntax as I couldn't find any examples of using Max, Min, Sum, Avg, ect - maybe I am just not understanding the documentation.

```
//Current way
extension String {
    var expression: NSExpression {
        return NSExpression(format: self)
    }
}

let results = formula.expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? Int
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

For anyone who needs this - you can take any string and use:

`functionName(x)` for most of the functions like `sqrt`, `multiplyby`, `trunc`, `ceiling`, ect

And then for the six with multiple variables (`max`, `min`, `count`, `average`, `sum`, and one other I forget) you use `functionName({x,y})`.

All can be used in a string with `expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil)`